# Webcam with FFmpeg on Mac: Selected framerate (29.970030) is not supported by the device

Tags: macos, ffmpeg, webcam

There was a very strange problem on Mac when I tried to access the webcam using FFmpeg.
For example:

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i "1" -framerate 60 -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/hls/test
```

No matter what framerate I set, the error was always the same.

```
[avfoundation @ 0x7ff831800000] Selected framerate (29.970030) is not supported by the device
[avfoundation @ 0x7ff831800000] Supported modes:
[avfoundation @ 0x7ff831800000]   320x240@[120.101366 120.101366]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x7ff831800000]   640x480@[120.101366 120.101366]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x7ff831800000]   800x600@[60.000240 60.000240]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x7ff831800000]   1024x768@[30.000030 30.000030]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x7ff831800000]   1280x720@[60.000240 60.000240]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x7ff831800000]   1280x1024@[30.000030 30.000030]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x7ff831800000]   1920x1080@[30.000030 30.000030]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x7ff831800000]   320x240@[30.000030 30.000030]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x7ff831800000]   640x480@[30.000030 30.000030]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x7ff831800000]   800x600@[20.000000 20.000000]fps
[avfoundation @ 0x7ff831800000]   1024x768@[6.000002 6.000002]fps
1: Input/output error
```

I've searched for this problem for many days but still can't find any solution. I'm very confused now.

I hope someone using Mac could try the similar command to access the webcam in order to see if this is a common problem.

Comment: You're setting `-framerate` as an output option. Placement of options matters. Try using it as an input option (before the `-i`). Also, you should always show the **complete** console output and not just an excerpt.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Wow! I tried the command `ffmpeg -f avfoundation -video_size 1920x1080 -framerate 30 -i "0" -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -f flv rtmp://localhost:1935/hls/test`, it works! What a ridiculous mistake I made! Could you please write an answer to this question? I will give you the reputation points. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You're setting `-framerate` as an output option instead of an input option. [Option location matters](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Synopsis), so move it before the `-i` and it will apply to the input instead:

```
ffmpeg -f avfoundation -framerate 60 -i default output.mp4
```

You also need to use a `-framerate` that is supported by your device, so arbitrary values may not be accepted. Refer to the output of `ffmpeg -f avfoundation -i <your device name>`.

Also see:

- [FFmpeg avfoundation documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#avfoundation)
- FFmpeg Wiki: Capture [Desktop](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Desktop#macOS) / [Webcam](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Capture/Webcam#AVFoundation) with avfoundation

Comment: After doing what you suggested ,no matter what framerate I provide it says framerate is not supported by the device.

Comment: @AnuranBarman I need to see the command you used and provide a link to the log.

Comment: the command I used is ffmpeg -framerate 1 -f avfoundation -i "0" -vcodec libx264 -preset veryfast -f rtsp rtsp://localhost:5554/live

the log is like this: https://pastebin.com/HycGFRbq

Comment: @AnuranBarman The device does not support your desired frame rate. You have to use a frame rate it supports. The output log you provided indicates which frame rates are supported.

Comment: The order of the arguments matter, this worked for me: `ffmpeg -f avfoundation -framerate 30 -i "default:none" output.mkv` .. notice first it's `-f` and then `-framerate`.